# What is the purpose of having multiple random vectors in a given problem/calculation?

Tags: probability, vectors

We just started covering random vectors in my college stats class, and I'm wondering what the purpose of having multiple random vectors is? For example; say we have two random vectors, $\vec{x}=[x_1,x_2,\cdots ,x_n]$, and $\vec{y}= [y_1,y_2,\cdots ,y_n]$. Each of the vectors, $\vec x$ and $\vec y$, is comprised of individual random variables, so why not combine the two vectors into one larger vector, like vector $\vec{x_y}= [x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2,\cdots ,x_n,y_n]$?

Comment: Fine.  No problem.  You can combine it if you want to.  Random vectors are just collections of random variables.  Sometimes it is useful to group them and use particular names for certain groups of random variables.

Comment: Did I offend someone with my glib language? Or maybe they don’t understand the answer? 

Comment: Your combined $\vec{x_y}$ might make questions like $\mathbb E[\vec{x}-\vec{y}]$ (another vector) more complicated to deal with

Answer (score 0):

If the variables were all iid (independent and identically distributed) you could conceivably combine them into 2n observations.

$$(X_1, ... X_n, Y_1, ...,  Y_n)$$

But there are scenarios where you would want to keep them separate. If the data are “paired” observations, e.g. come from a bivariate normal distribution and are correlated with each other. Or are just paired with each other, such as measurements from your left foot and right foot and do a paired t-test. It’s also possible they come from different distributions. Like normal distributions (our favorite...) from two populations, and you want to test if the means or whatever are the same/different.

Oh I forgot random vectors are entities too. So like a multivariate normal random vector. The entries are correlated with each other. So you might want to keep them separate.

$$(X_1, ..., X_n)\sim \text {Normal}(\mu, \Sigma)$$

Comment: Thanks! The example about the feet and populations cleared it up for me.